# How to move some activities into separate row in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have standard social share via Facebook and Twitter using `UIActivityViewController`.

How can I add extra row/line above (like third one) in `UIActivityViewController` and move some activities (facebook, twitter) on that additional row/line?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. UIActivityViewController only supports the two rows. This is defined by the activity's category type.

Comment: Yes, I thought of this ). Thank you